# ExtJS 4 desktop - how to set desktop shortcut tooltip

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs-mvc

What's the best way to set a tooltip for a desktop shortcut?

In my getDesktopConfig() I create an array of shortcut data with fields iconCls, module, name.  Here's an example of adding a Users module shortcut to the array and then setting the array as the data property of the shortcuts data store, which is used to create the desktop shortcuts:

```
Ext.define("MyDesktop.App", {
extend: "Ext.ux.desktop.App",

....

getDesktopConfig:            function () {
    var b = this;
    var a = b.callParent();

    .....

    shortcut_data.push({
            iconCls:        "users-shortcut",
            module:         "users-module-window",
            name:           "Users"
        });

    ......

    return Ext.apply(a,{
        contextMenuItems:    [{
            text:           "Dashboards",
            handler:         b.onDashboards,
            scope:           b
        }],
        shortcuts:           Ext.create("Ext.data.Store",{
            model:          "Ext.ux.desktop.ShortcutModel",
            data:            shortcut_data
        }),
        wallpaper:          "/assets/MyApp_Wallpaper.jpg",
        wallpaperStretch:    false
    })
})
},
.....
```

Comment: You are missing a critical piece of information. What is the component that renders the shortcut? If this is you shortcut config {
            iconCls:        "users-shortcut",
            module:         "users-module-window",
            name:           "Users"
        }   what does it get applied to?

Comment: Shortcuts are added to the desktop app. Updating question.

Comment: I understand. But I am not familiar with this app, can you provide the ExtJS Component type of the shortcut icon? Is it a derivative of a button?

Comment: The "shortcuts" object on the desktop is a Ext.data.Store. Each "shortcut" item is a Ext.ux.desktop.ShortcutModel, whose definition is: Ext.define("Ext.ux.desktop.ShortcutModel",{extend:"Ext.data.Model",fields:[{name:"name"},{name:"iconCls"},{name:"module"}]});

Comment: You are confused. The store is just an array of records. Each record is a config for one Shortcut. But this config is applied to a Component that renders your Shortcut.  That Component is probably an Ext.Button ... right?

Answer (score 1):

Add a field to Ext.ux.desktop.ShortcutModel for your tooltip. Here, I have named it qtipText. Ext.ux.desktop.ShortcutModel show now look like this:

```
Ext.define('Ext.ux.desktop.ShortcutModel', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: [
       { name: 'name' },
       { name: 'iconCls' },
       { name: 'module' },
       { name: 'qtipText' }
    ]
});
```

Now when you define your shortcuts, add this field with value for the tooltip:

```
shortcut_data.push({
            iconCls:        "users-shortcut",
            module:         "users-module-window",
            name:           "Users",
            qtipText:       "Open Users Window"
        });
```

In initComponent method of Ext.ux.desktop.Desktop, you will see that there is a listener for itemclick event for shortcutsView. Just add another listener for itemmouseenter event:

```
me.shortcutsView.on('itemmouseenter', me.onShortcutItemMouseEnter, me);
```

define the handler as follows:

```
onShortcutItemMouseEnter: function (dataView, record) {
    if(!dataView.tip)
         dataView.tip = Ext.create('Ext.tip.ToolTip', {
          target: dataView.el,
          delegate: dataView.itemSelector,                            
          trackMouse: true,
          html: record.get('qtipText')
      });
    else
      dataView.tip.update(record.get('qtipText'));
},
```

dataView.tip doesnt exist on first time and we create a tooltip for this view. later, we just update the tip text according to the record (corresponding to the shortcut on which the mouse has moved over).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the shortcuts are generated by a button derivative I would go with tooltip:'some text' config for the shortcut_data .

Comment: It would make sense, and it's the first thing I tried, including adding that property to the ShortcutModel. No luck there.

Comment: do any tooltips work? Meaning, has qtips been initialized through: Ext.QuickTips.init();

Comment: Please take a look at the Sencha demo desktop app: [demo desktop](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/example/desktop/desktop.html)